# Read text from .xls in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I try to read the .xls flies in c#.
If the first data column is text then it says `DBNull.Value =true`.
But if it number it is OK.
So How do I read the text?

This is my code:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select [Id], [Name], [Email] from [sheet$]", connection);

OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
objAdapter .SelectCommand = command;

DataSet objDataset = new DataSet();

objAdapter .Fill(objDataset1);
DataView dv = objDataset .Tables[0].DefaultView;

for (int i = 0; i < dv.Count; i++)
{
    if (dv[i][0] != DBNull.Value ) // problem is here.... if the first column is text then it true. I want to tead text as well.
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. what exactly is the problem you're encountering?

Comment: If the first column type it test it says DBNull.Value =true. So I want to read the column if it is type is text.

Comment: You mean you want to test if it is a string and then use the value if it is?

Comment: yes.i want to test if type is what ever

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
string dval = dv[i][0] as string;
if(dval != null)
{
    //use string
```

To use the string, you will have to call the `ToString()` method. i.e.:

```
dv[i][0].ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For DBNull checks use [Convert.IsDBNull(object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.isdbnull.aspx) method.
2. For reading values as text, use [Convert.ToString(object, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131014.aspx) method or typecast.

I.e. may be you are need a something next:

```
if(!Convert.IsDBNull(dv[i][0])) {…
// or
var text = Convert.ToString(dv[i][0], CultureInfo.CurentCulture);
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) {…
// or
var text = dv[i][0] as string;
if(text != null) {…
```

depended on what you need.

Comment: If the first column type it test it says DBNull.Value =true. So I want to read the column if it is type is text.

Answer (score 0):

Are you restricted to using the `OleDbDataAdapter` or are you able to use other libraries? If you can you may want to give [linqtoexcel](https://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/) a go. I found it much easier to use because I am a big fan of linq. Its available from the link above, but its also available on nuget.

This is the sort of syntax you'd be using:

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory("excelFileName");
var indianaCompanies = from c in excel.Worksheet()
                       where c["State"] == "IN" || c.Zip == 46550
                       select c;
```

where you have a spreadsheet called `excelFileName` and the data you want is on the first worksheet, you then select any rows where the `State` column (column names are assumed to be in the first row) equals `IN` or the `Zip` column = `46550`. They have a wiki page with loads more examples on [here](https://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/wiki/UsingLinqToExcel)